# Unity - DontDestroyOnLoad - FindObjectsOfType(GetType()).Length is always returning 1

Tags: unity, c#, unity-networking, instancing, unet

I'm trying to have an object with the `DontDestroyOnLoad` property. I want an object with NetworkIdentity to persist across scenes, so I can have a holder script for RPCs.

[This answer](http://answers.unity3d.com/answers/485933/view.html) suggests the following code:

```
public void Awake()
{
    DontDestroyOnLoad(this);

    if (FindObjectsOfType(GetType()).Length > 1)
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Despite this, I still end up with duplicate objects. `FindObjectsOfType(GetType()).Length` is always returning 1, and I don't know why, or how to fix it. It makes no difference whether this object is a prefab instance or a simple object in the hierarchy.

I have also tried to clone this object in my NetworkManager script, which is automatically persistent, but `GameObject.Find("ObjectNameHere(Clone)")` is always returning false. However, the above solution seems simpler so I'd prefer to figure out  `FindObjectsOfType(GetType()).Length`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You better use Singleton pattern which ensures that object will exist in in a single copy:

```
public class ExampleClass: MonoBehaviour {
    public static ExampleClass instance = null;

    void Start () {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = this;
        } else if(instance != this){
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }

        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);

        InitializeManager();
    }

    private void InitializeManager(){
        // TODO: add initialization code here
    }
}
```

And you don`t even need to use heavy FindObjectsOfType() method.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It compares time alive on different instances of the class, ensuring that your first instance will be the one that survives.

```
public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {

    float time = 0;

    void Awake () {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(this);
    }

    void Update () {
        time += Time.deltaTime;
    }

    private void OnLevelWasLoaded(int level)
    {
        foreach (ExampleClass classInstance in FindObjectsOfType<ExampleClass>())
        {
            if (classInstance.time < time)
            {
                Destroy(classInstance);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps. It's not the way you would like, but it is functional.

Comment: Why would you bother checking each frame for time if you can atleast toggle a simple bool upon first object initialization?